# One mouse click is registered twice C++ / GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have to make some transformation with left mouse click. This is part of my code:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && v*p + xk <= 34 && v*p + yk <= 34 && v*p - xk <= 34 && v*p - yk <= 34) {
    std::cout << "Resized" << std::endl;
    p += 0.02;

    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

But when I do click once on the screen, it prints "Resized" twice. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`glutMouseFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node50.html) is invoked once, when the mouse is pressed and once when the mouse is released.
When the mouse is pressed, then the actual *state* argument is `GLUT_DOWN`. When the mouse is released then the argument is `GLUT_UP`.

Additionally test if `state == GLUT_DOWN`:

```cpp
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

    if (state == GLUT_DOWN &&                      // <----
        button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON &&
        v*p + xk <= 34 && v*p + yk <= 34 && v*p - xk <= 34 && v*p - yk <= 34) {

        std::cout << "Resized" << std::endl;
        p += 0.02;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. How do I fix that?

Comment: @m evaluate if `state == GLUT_DOWN`. I've extended the the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means that this your mouse() function is called twice somewhere. Most likely you register the handler to that function twice.

Comment: You mean in the main()? I don't have it twice anywhere. Sometimes it registers it once, but only if it's really close to the border of the screen (conditions in the If statement written above). Other times it always clicks twice, both on USB mouse and on laptop touchpad.